# cannot pass object dynamically in function in extjs/javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to perform click action on a displayfield in extjs. It doesn't have click listeners so i added `<a></a>` tags in its html as follows:

```
obj = {a: 123, b: 'abc' }

html: '<a href="javascript: Ext.ux.classobj.method('+obj+')" ><img src="image.png" /></a>'
```

The problem is I can't pass object dynamically. Means the above `<a></a>` doesn't call the method and fires an error as it calls :

```
javascript: Ext.ux.classobj.method(object Object)
```

However, if i use static values like

```
  html: '<a href="javascript: Ext.ux.classobj.method({a:123, b:'abc'})" ><img src="image.png" /></a>'
```

This method will be called without any error as it calls:

```
javascript: Ext.ux.classobj.method({a:123, b:'abc'})
```

Does anyone knows how to do this? Thanks a lot for help

Regards

Comment: Sounds like a scope problem.  Your code defining "obj" and an "html" property seem to be from different parts of the code... it would be useful to see the context of these lines.

Comment: @typeof: It is not a scope problem. Whenever you concatenate an object with a string, the default string value for an object is `[object Object]`

Comment: Ah yes... couldn't see the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 1):

The default `toString` of an object just returns "[object Object]" which (as you found out) isn't what you want.

I'd step back and ask, if you're using a framework like ExtJS which provides quite rich functionality, why are you falling back on the `onclick` attribute on an anchor? ExtJS (like most other JavaScript libraries) provides a means of hooking an event on an object in a more modern way, a way in which you could use `obj` directly.

I haven't used ExtJS in years, so I'm afraid I don't recall the direct way to do this, but I think it's either [`EventManager.addListener`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.EventManager) or more likely some shorthand for it like [`Element#on`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Element.html#method-Ext.Element-on). So you'd add your anchor (or span, or whatever), and then use `addListener` to add a `click` event handler which uses `obj` directly. Something like:

```
var obj = {a: 123, b: 'abc' };
Ext.get('theId').on('click', function() {
    Ext.ux.classobj.method(obj);
});
```

...or, of course, simply:

```
Ext.get('theId').on('click', function() {
    Ext.ux.classobj.method({a: 123, b: 'abc' });
});
```

...but again, my ExtJS-fu is very weak these days.

Answer (score 0):

Change your html assignment to:

**Using Ext.util.JSON.encode:**

```
html: '<a href="javascript: Ext.ux.classobj.method(' + Ext.util.JSON.encode
(obj) + ')" ><img src="image.png" /></a>'
```

**Using JSON.stringify:**

```
html: '<a href="javascript: Ext.ux.classobj.method(' + JSON.stringify(obj) + ')" ><img src="image.png" /></a>'
```

Comment: **If** they have a JSON library, yeah.

Comment: Agreed.Updated the post with an option using Extjs native function to stringify

Comment: Still doesn't give a reference to the object, only a JSON representation of the object at the time encode was called. Of course, the is a great answher if that is what is wanted... hard to imagine, but possible.

Comment: You can use JSON representation of the object to use the object, unless I misunderstood your question. Can you pls explain?

Comment: @Cybernate me? Sure. If you encode `obj = {a:1}` and then modify it with `obj.b = 2`; the encoded string will not contain b. When the event fires the event will receive an object like `{a:1}` not `{a:1,b:2}` since the argument was encoded to a string before b was added.

Comment: In that case, what Felix Kling has suggested is a better solution so that you have a global object that contains the changes made to the object after the anchor is tagged to onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

If `obj` is global, you have to write:

```
<a href="javascript: Ext.ux.classobj.method(obj)" ><img src="image.png" /></a>
```

If you make string concatenation, then you are getting the string value of the object which by default is `[object Object]`.

Comment: What is obj changes by the time user clicks the anchor?

Comment: @Cybernate: What do you mean? `obj` will have the value that it has when the button is clicked.

Comment: I think he's worried about `obj` having changed between when he defined it and when the button is clicked.

Comment: @TJCrowder: I see.... well that depends on what the OP actually wants. Of course it can change over time.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
var obj = { /* ...  */ };

//  ...
{
  xtype: 'displayfield',
  html: '<img src="image.png" />', // notice no <a> needed
  listeners: {
    render: function() {
      this.el.on('click', function() {
        Ext.ux.classobj.method(obj);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, wait for the DisplayField to render and then add the click listener to the el backing the component. As long as obj is available via [closure](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml), you're fine.

You could also use `createDelegate` to bind obj as the lone argument for the event handler:

```
this.el.on('click', 
   Ext.ux.classobj.method.createDelegate(Ext.ux.classobj, [obj]));
```